# SUBSTITUTING VARIBALE IN SED ESCAPING $

Tags: awk, sed

I have 20 lines in file i want to remove all lines after nth line
nth line number is set using varible
eg var1=5 then remove line 5 to 20 using sed

Tried
`sed ""$var1",$d" file -i`

But it produces following error

````
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unexpected `,'```
````

Comment: the shell is expanding `$d` to an empty string. You need to escape the `$` so it is passed untouched to sed.

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
var="3"
awk -v line="$var" '1; FNR==line{exit}' file > temp && mv temp file
```

**Details:**

Here we are creating a shell variable `var` with value `3`, then we are passing that variable to awk program, now the `awk` program is printing every `line` till the line number is `3` then the program is exited.

Comment: @DaichiAsh Shubham showed how to do "inplace" editing for any command (by manually doing exactly what `sed -i` and every other command except `ed` does behind the scenes) but also - just like GNU sed has the `-i` option for inplace editing, GNU awk has `-i inplace`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
export var1=5
perl -i.bak -pe 'last if $. == $ENV{var1}' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: But i want infile edit to remove all lines till last line from line number specified by variable without creating any temp file

Comment: @DaichiAsh `sed -i` creates a temp file too, as does `perl -i`, `gawk -i inplace`, `ruby -i`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I was beginner to linux thats why i asked such question.
Since no one answered.
I kept trying.

Now i learned how to debug linux shells and hence while using set -x i encountered mistake i was doing while writing up this command.
Now it is solved.

```
var=2
sed ""$(echo "$var")",\$d" file
```